# Update partialview element in parent View from within partialview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

**INDEX PAGE**

My Index page has a div that fetches a partialview:

```
<div class="row row-centered">
    <div id="divPickings" class="col-sm-12 table-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript loading:

```
function getPickings() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/home/GetPendingPickings")'+window.location.search,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#divPickings').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**PARTIAL VIEW**

My partial view is stronly typed with a simple foreach loop creating a table and buttons for action. I have a click handler that is working ok.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.available,.reserved').click(function () {
            reservePickSlip();
            //REFRESH ME!!!!!!
        });
    });
</script>
```

**REQUIREMENT:**

AFTER the button completes the `reservePickSlip()` operation i need to refresh the partialview itself.

I can of course put a button in index page and have it manually but i want it to happen automatically.

Comment: then again make ajax call render that partial view.

Comment: You should be able to just call `getPickings()`, right where `//REFRESH ME!!!!!!` currently stands

Comment: This code is IN PARTIAL VIEW..Iwant to trigger the parent index.cshtml to render the partialview somehow! So i click a button IN the partialview, does the job, BUT then i have to update the partialview without having to tell the user to press a button in index page

Comment: what if you re-draw the partial view itself after clicking the buttons? by using the UpdateTaregtId?

Comment: @HadiHassan can you please exlpain more?

Comment: you can build your partial view as Ajax form, which will allow you to call the buttons and the returned view will be rendered in the UpdateTargetId that you specified, check this sample http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PartialView-and-Ajax-bb05c909

Comment: But the partialview is being called from parent index page via jquery ajax request....If you still think this will give me a solution , yes please by all means provide an answer with a sample code.

Comment: i edited my last comment and i put a link that will answer enshallah what you are looking for, your situation is for example  like you have a search page and when you click the search you want to update the result which is List of data in a partial view, again this is the solution you are searching on i think, http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PartialView-and-Ajax-bb05c909